# ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder561233561/bin/start.sh: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm using centos7 in virtual box

I was starting to create a service

After running  COPY ./bin/start.sh /start.sh, its throwing the below error

```
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder561233561/bin/start.sh: no such file or directory
```

Image shows the folder structure

DockerFile

```
FROM remote-host

COPY ./conf/nginx.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo

RUN                                                                          \
  yum -y install nginx-1.12.2 openssl --enablerepo=nginx                  && \
  yum -y install https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm         && \
  yum -y install                                                             \
    php72u-fpm                                                               \
    php72u-cli                                                               \
    php72u-mysqlnd                                                           \
    php72u-soap                                                              \
    php72u-xml                                                               \
    php72u-zip                                                               \
    php72u-json                                                              \
    php72u-mcrypt                                                            \
    php72u-mbstring                                                          \
    php72u-zip                                                               \
    php72u-gd                                                                \
     --enablerepo=ius && yum clean all

EXPOSE 80 443

VOLUME /var/www/html /var/log/nginx /var/log/php-fpm /var/lib/php-fpm

COPY ./conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY ./bin/start.sh /start.sh

RUN chmod +x /start.sh

CMD /start.sh
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins-ansible
    build:
      context: jenkins-ansible
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
    networks:
      - net
  remote_host:
    container_name: remote-host
    image: remote-host
    build:
      context: centos7
    volumes:
      - $PWD/script.sh:/tmp/newScript.sh
    networks:
      - net
  db_host:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - net
  web:
    container_name: web
    image: ansible-web
    build:
      context: jenkins-ansible/web
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - net

networks:
  net:
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcDzY.png)
The image shows the project structure
Please help me out to remove this error

Comment: Please do not post links to images of text. Just post the text. What is `remote-host`? So where is the file `./bin/start.sh` you expect to `COPY`?

Comment: I'm completely new to these concepts
start.sh is to run the script present in the bin folder which shown in the image

Comment: No, you didn't show the contents of the bin directory in your image. You showed that a start.sh exists in `jenkins-data`.